# My cursor gets only last entry from sql database, but I need all of them

Tags: java, android, sql

every one. I'm trying to get data from database, but it shows me only the last entry. The same code works for other entries, but for long it doesn't. I have searched a lot and always answer is teh same I have, so I don't know what to do. My code:

```
hepublic void loadRevenueDate() {

    String dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    long l=0;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Open database
    db.open();

    Cursor c = db.getRevData();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            l = c.getLong(3);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    cal.setTimeInMillis(l);
    String date = formater.format(cal.getTime());
    revDate.setText(date);


    // Close the cursor
    c.close();
    c = null;

    // And close the database
    db.close();
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor *correctly* reads over *all* the records - but *you overwrite and ignore previous values* when re-assigning to the `l` variable.

Do the thing "per row" *inside* the loop or otherwise save the relevant data into a collection such as an `ArrayList`. I imagine your UI needs to be redesigned, but this won't "skip" any values:

```
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // Stuff that happens for EACH record
        long l = c.getLong(3);
        cal.setTimeInMillis(l);
        String date = formater.format(cal.getTime());

        // .. and actually save the data for use later
        dates.add(date)
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}

// To make the text pretty (e.g. without surrounding braces),
// search for "java list join" or otherwise consume the List in the UI
// in a meaningful fashion.
revDate.setText("" + dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code it looks like you're just iterating over the values until you get to the last one. If you want to do something with all the values, you need to add something into the loop:

```
public void loadRevenueDate() {

String dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
long l=0;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// Open database
db.open();

Cursor c = db.getRevData();

long accum = 0;

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        l = c.getLong(3);   

        // Do something here. For example:
        accum += l;  

    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
cal.setTimeInMillis(l);
String date = formater.format(cal.getTime());
revDate.setText(date);


// Close the cursor
c.close();
c = null;

// And close the database
db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you loop through all the result rows, assigning the long value from each row to 'l' over and over (overwriting the previous value), before you do anything with 'l'. So by the time you come to use 'l' (once the looping has finished), it will only contain the value from the final row.

If you wish to do something with each value you assign to 'l', you need to do it within the do...while loop. I.e.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            l = c.getLong(3);

            //Do the actual thing with this row's 'l' here
            //E.g.
            System.out.println("l is currently set to: " + l);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

Hope that makes sense.